# Pick class method from factory interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have some class what I access using factory, factory provide 4 class, class provide 4 methods, in total 16 methods, for minimize dependency (for mock factory in unit tests), I decide simulate interface segregation principle, for it I decide Pick only using class, and for it, pick only using methods

For it I write next solution

```
type aType = {
  get(): string,
  edit(): string,
  remove(): void,
}

type bType = {
  get(): number,
  remove(): void,
}

type factory = {
  a(): aType,
  b(): bType,
}


const f: factory = {
  a: () => ({
    get: () => 'status',
    edit: () => 'u',
    remove() {}
  }),
  b: () => ({
    get: () => 24,
    remove() {}
  })
}


type PickClassFactory<T extends Record<string, any>, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof ReturnType<T[K1]>> = {
  [P1 in K1]: () => {
    [P2 in K2]: () => ReturnType<ReturnType<(T[K1])>[P2]>;
  };
};

type getFactory = PickClassFactory<factory, 'a' | 'b', 'get'>;

const truncF : getFactory = f;
```

but problem what return type of methods from original factory not coincide with return type for methods from new factory interface

```
f.b().get() // number
truncF.b().get() // string | number
```

I don't known how extend my generic for resolve this, possible trivial task

for write PickClassFactory generic I modify this generic from Pick2 https://gist.github.com/staltz/368866ea6b8a167fbdac58cddf79c1bf

Answer (score 0):

Result differ because instead iterate by each key for generate result type, using single union for all keys what generate result for all keys as union

For fix it I change this line

```
[P2 in K2]: () => ReturnType<ReturnType<(T[K1])>[P2]>;
```

to

```
[P2 in K2]: () => ReturnType<ReturnType<(T[P1])>[P2]>;
```